# WebMobileGroupChatServer : The requested resource is not available

Tags: android, jquery

I'm following the [example here](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/) to build a simple group chat app using sockets.

I downloaded the file `jquery-1.11.1.min`  [from phpclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/52742.html) but it doesn't work.

This is what I'm getting as a result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Thx3.png)

> Description:The requested resource is not available.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with the routing in your local server. Can you add configuration details? Are you sure all files are in the right place?

Comment: Removed unnecessary text, introduced formatting, corrected grammar

Comment: Thank you Mr Graham